# How may I export my data from Google Drive and Mail without access to Google Takeout?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace

I have an account in an organization and have been given permission to retain my emails and files before it is deleted. However, my administrator has disabled access to Google Takeout. I have a lot of files and emails and one week to save them. Is there a way for me to retrieve them without resorting to manually copying?

I am content with any file format so long as the data (and ideally also metadata) is accessible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask your admin to enable Takeout.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: If you can, enable POP/IMAP and download them through a local client!

Answer (score 1):

I had used Mailstore (a 3rd party application) that is very good for email self-archiving - free for home use https://www.mailstore.com/en/products/mailstore-home/

Not affiliated with them - just very happy user (as I have used this against Outlook.com, Yahoo.com and Gmail account)